# CakePHP 2.x: How to use different column names for the Created, Modified automated fields?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have an application and everything is in Spanish, even the tables names and their columns.

I want to map or create an alias or something in order to use the CakePHP Created, Modified automated fields.

Example:

`created => fecha_creacion`

`modified => fecha_modificacion`

Thanks!

Comment: For the record: It's a bad idea to have everything in spanish. the code and the table names should be in english. Makes your life way easier - don't fight the framework..

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mark but this is a project for the university and since I'm from Paraguay my teachers would not accept it that way. I'm thinking on redoing the project after is completed to make it open source so by that time I will take care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done. You can however, put logic in `AppModel::beforeSave` or `AppModel::save` to recreate the automagic behaviour. [DboSource::expression](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-DboSource.html#_expression) is the preferred way of doing this, but you could also use `date` or the TimeHelper.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    // it's an insert, so add `created`
    if(empty($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['fecha_creacion'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');
    }

    // modified is set anyway
    $this->data[$this->alias]['fecha_modificacion'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');

    return true;
}
```